# Fetching all data from FireBase database to a spinner

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my FireBase data Structure
[image]

I would like help to retrieve the groupname from each id from the database and push it to a spinner.

I already tried in ListView and retrieved them, now I want them in a spinner

```
databaseGroups.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        list.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot groupSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            BuddyGroup buddyGroup=groupSnapshot.getValue(BuddyGroup.class);
                            list.add(buddyGroup);

                            GroupList adapter= new GroupList(member_auth.this,list);
                            listViewGroup.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

What changes should I make? Please help

Comment: use notifychanged method to a adaptr after adding(chagning) data.it may work

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: @Vishal have you got the solution?

Comment: yes@NarenderReddy